# How Do i pass a Public variable from one form to another

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms, variables

I Am trying to pass 2 variables from one form and have another form open and i want to use thos same variables from the last form to query a sql database to populate it with data based on information from the last form

I need FName and LName from this form Set by parameters passed by the method Information.

```
Public Class UserProfile
Public IMEI As String
Public FName As String
Public LName As String

Public Sub Information(FName As String, LName As String, Dob As String, Phone As String, PhoneType As String, IMEI As String, AppleGoogleID As String, AppleGooglePass As String, Phoneswap As Integer, LockScreen As String)
    Dim UserData As New UserDataInventory
    FName = FName
    LName = LName
    NameLbl.Text = FName + " " + LName
    If Dob Is "" Then
        DOBLbl.Text = "Date of Birth not on file."
    Else
        DOBLbl.Text = Dob
    End If
    PhoneLbl.Text = Phone
    Dim TelephoneModel As String
    If PhoneType Is Nothing Then
        PhoneTypeLbl.Text = "USER IMEI NOT ON FILE, ENTER IMEI INTO DATABASE!"
        TelephoneModel = Nothing
    Else
        PhoneTypeLbl.Text = PhoneType
        TelephoneModel = PhoneType.Substring(0, PhoneType.IndexOf(" "))
    End If
    IMEINumLbl.Text = IMEI


    If TelephoneModel = "Apple" Then
        UsernameLbl.Text = "AppleID Username:"
        UsernameOutputLbl.Text = AppleGoogleID
        PasswordLbl.Text = "AppleID Password:"
        PassLbl.Text = AppleGooglePass
    ElseIf TelephoneModel = "Samsung" Then
        UsernameLbl.Text = "GoogleID Username:"
        UsernameOutputLbl.Text = AppleGoogleID
        PasswordLbl.Text = "GoogleID Password:"
        PassLbl.Text = AppleGooglePass
    ElseIf PhoneType Is Nothing Then
        UsernameLbl.Text = "Username:"
        UsernameOutputLbl.Text = AppleGoogleID
        PasswordLbl.Text = "Password:"
        PassLbl.Text = AppleGooglePass

    End If
    If LockScreen = "" Then
        LockLbl.Text = "None on File"
    Else
        LockLbl.Text = LockScreen
    End If
    PhoneSwapsLbl.Text = Phoneswap
    SwapCountLbl.Text = UserData.SwapCountNumber(FName, LName)

    Dim name = UserData.pictureNameFormatting(FName, LName)
    Dim Folder As String = "G:\PUBLIC\HelpDesk\Public\Data\pictures"
    Dim Filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Folder, name & ".JPG")
    PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Filename)
    PictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch

End Sub

Private Sub CloseBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseBtn.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintBtn.Click

End Sub

Private Sub RecQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RecQuery.Click
    Try
        Dim IMEI As String = IMEINumLbl.Text
        Dim MobileInv As New MobileInventory
        MobileInv.SqlBlob2File(IMEI)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("No Receipt on File.")
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub PhoneHistoryBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PhoneHistoryBtn.Click
    Dim SwapHistory As New SwapHistory
    SwapHistory.Show()


End Sub
End Class
```

And i need to populate to variables on this form below for data manipulation.

```
Public Class SwapHistory
Public FName = UserProfile.FName
Public LName = UserProfile.LName

Private Sub SwapHistory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'UserCellPhoneHistory._UserCellPhoneHistory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.UserCellPhoneHistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UserCellPhoneHistory._UserCellPhoneHistory)
    NameLbl.Text = LName + ", " + FName
End Sub

Private Sub CancelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelBtn.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The easiest thing is to either create some public properties and set them, or a method to pass the 2 vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the simplest ways is to customize the New constructor:

```
Public Class SwapHistory
Public FName = UserProfile.FName
Public LName = UserProfile.LName

Public Sub New(fName as String, lName as string)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Fname = fName
    LName = lName
End Sub
Private Sub SwapHistory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'UserCellPhoneHistory._UserCellPhoneHistory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.UserCellPhoneHistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.UserCellPhoneHistory._UserCellPhoneHistory)
    NameLbl.Text = LName + ", " + FName
End Sub

Private Sub CancelBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelBtn.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

End Sub
End Class
```

Then to show the form:

```
Private Sub PhoneHistoryBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PhoneHistoryBtn.Click
    Dim SwapHistory As New SwapHistory(FName, LName)
    SwapHistory.Show()


End Sub
```

Comment: AHH YES this is what I  need